# Typeorm exclude primary key column from select

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I know that you can add a select false option to a column in order to exclude it from being selected. However, in my case the two columns I want to exclude are the primary keys of the entity. When I set them to false it does not work and still includes them. I can imagine that typeorm can't exclude them because they are needed to identify the entity or because they are a FK to another relation.

Here is my example:

```
import { Entity, Column, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Timestamps } from "../../shared/entities/timestamps.entity";
import { User } from "../../users/entities/users.entity";
import { Project } from './project.entity';


@Entity('project_invites')
export class ProjectInvite extends Timestamps {

    // Joined Column
    @PrimaryColumn({select: false) // <= Does not work
    invitedUserId: string;

    // Joined Column
    @PrimaryColumn({select: false}) // <= Does not work
    projectId: string;

    @Column({select: false})
    fromUserId: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    message: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'invitedUserId' })
    invitedUser: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Project, (project) => project.members, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'projectId' })
    project: Project;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.projectInvites, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'fromUserId' })
    fromUser: User;

}
```

I use the `invitedUserId, fromUserId, projectID` column to insert the entity with it's relations. But when I query the data I only want to include joined relations. Is there any other way I can approach this with Typeorm or do I have to manually remove the attributes from the result?

Answer (score 0):

> Primary keys will always be selected - they're crucial to orm internal logic(operating on entity later on). We could remove select from PrimaryColumn, GeneratedPrimaryColumn options though.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5556#issuecomment-589955182